# Is this a correct way to use .htaccess to redirect a user to a folder?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I got wordpress installed in /WP. So i browsed the web to find an example of a htaccess that can redirect the user from domain.se to domain.se/wp. So if anyone just types in the domain name then they will be redirected to the /wp folder.

This was the one i found and it works.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.se/wp/$1 [R,L]
```

Question is, is it ok like this or is this a bad solution?

Comment: Did you test and is this working properly?

Comment: But your code can't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code should be the following :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.se/wp/$1 [R,L]
```